# Avoid breaking loop in discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I have discord.py robot that run in linux, and I want to modify it to only delete and send some message and go away.

robot version goes in background (`fork()`+`client.run()`) and I stopped it using `kill $(< file.pid)`
messenger version do almost the same, but I use `client.close()` once message is send.

the code to send message is adapted from robot, however I feel `client.run()/client.close()` is a poor choice.

what is proper coding convention in this case ?

code snippet :

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import discord

jeu = discord.Game("foo")
client = discord.Client()


async def effacer_anciens_message(channel) :
    async for message in channel.history(limit=20) :
        if message.author == client.user :
            await message.delete()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(activity=jeu)
    for server in client.guilds :
        print (f"{server.name} a pour ID {server.id}")
        if server.name == "my server" :
            for channel in server.channels :
                if channel.name == "my channel" :
                    ## delete some message
                    await effacer_anciens_message(channel) 
                    ## print/send some message
                    await channel.send("Et maintenant, quelques informations ... ")
                    await afficher_event(channel)

    await client.close()

client.run(get_discord_token())

print("disconnected")
```

(this code work, `afficher_event()` send some message, and `get_discord_token()` return proper value)

Answer (score 0):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import discord

jeu = discord.Game("foo")
client = discord.Client()


async def effacer_anciens_message(channel) :
    async for message in channel.history(limit=20) :
        if message.author == client.user :
            await message.delete()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(activity=jeu)
    for server in client.guilds:
        print (f"{server.name} a pour ID {server.id}")
        if server.name != "my server":
            continue
          for channel in server.channels:
              if channel.name != "my channel":
                  continue
                ## delete some message
                await effacer_anciens_message(channel) 
                ## print/send some message
                await channel.send("Et maintenant, quelques informations ... ")
                await afficher_event(channel)

    print("disconnected")
    exit(1)

client.run(get_discord_token())
```